Use PostgreSQL for Spring Authorization server
I have this configuration for JdbcTemplate used with Spring Authorization Server:
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabase;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;

@Bean
public EmbeddedDatabase embeddedDatabase() {
    // @formatter:off
    // TODO Change type to non embedded SQL
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .generateUniqueName(true)
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
            .setScriptEncoding("UTF-8")
            .addScript("org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/oauth2-authorization-schema.sql")
            .addScript("org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/oauth2-authorization-consent-schema.sql")
            .addScript("org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/client/oauth2-registered-client-schema.sql")
            .build();
    // @formatter:on
}

I would like to replace this code to work with PostgreSQL database.
What change I need to make?

You're gonna need the database schemas that works with Postgres. Replace types that doesn't work in Postgres like blob. This issue might help: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/1253
